# Should the Greek definite article be omitted in a ὅτι phrase?

Tags: greek, articles

In phrases like, *we wish to be attacked by as few enemies as possible*, ἐθέλομεν προσβάλλεσθαι ὑφ' ὅτι ὀλιγίστων πολεμίων, is it correct to leave out the definite article after ὅτι? I ask because, in English, it would be grammatically wrong to place a definite article inside the phrase *as few enemies as possible*. The word "few" (ὀλιγίστων) seems to take the place of the definite article, in the same way that the indefinite adjectives τις and τι would. If the omission is correct, is it due to the ὅτι construction?

Comment: My Greek is rusty, but shouldn't that be "hos" not "hoti"?

Comment: According to my textbook, both words can be used interchangeably. See the second definition at Wiktionary: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ὅτι.

Comment: Not an answer because I don't have any evidence, but my sense is that you wouldn't want a definite article here. The enemies aren't definite, as far as I can see. In any case ὑφ΄ ὅτι τῶν ὀλιγίστων πολεμίων is definitely wrong; the position of τῶν looks ungrammatical to me.

Comment: @brianpck. ὅ τι is correct. See my answer.

Comment: @fdb Do you know if they are strictly interchangeable, if used in this way? I seem to recall "hos" being more frequent, but that's just anecdotal.

Comment: @brianpck. ὠς seems to be used in this meaning only with sup. adverbs, not with adjectives.

Comment: @fdb, ὡς is used in this sense with adjectives too: LSJ gives e.g. ὅπως ὡς βέλτισται ἔσονται (Plato).

Comment: By the way, since the enemies are countable, a better choice in this context might be ὅσος, which can be used with a superlative like ὅτι / ὡς: "... ὑπὸ πολεμίων ὅσων ὀλιγίστων". Also ἐθέλω (in Attic prose anyway) is more about "being willing" or "consenting" than more active "wanting", so I'd use βουλόμεθα here instead.

Comment: @TKR Interesting! That word hasn't appeared in my textbook, though. If I must use οτι, would my example be the best way? (i.e., with the noun after οτι).

Comment: @ktm5124 I'm not sure I've ever seen ὅτι/ὡς/ὅσος + adj. appearing between a preposition and its noun, which is why I went for the opposite order, but it may well be fine; only a corpus search would tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.53:9:58.LSJ

ὅ τι (or ὅτι) is combined with a superlative adverb or a superlative adjective to mean “as X as possible”. In both cases it seems that it is never used with a definite article (see the quotations in LSJ). In the case of the adverbial usage this makes sense, and the adjectival usage is perhaps by analogy with the former.